# In WSL2, enabling systemd break gui applications

Tags: debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wayland

In WSL2 (1.0.3) with Debian Testing, gui applications work fine. But when I enable 'systemd', they don't work anymore.

In /etc/wsl.conf:

```
[boot]
systemd = true
```

Applications start (the shell is waiting for the app), but the GUI is not visible (ex: firefox, xterm, xclock, gedit). If I type some text, it show up in the shell. Typing exit <kbd>Return</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> does nothing.

[image]

Comment: Does this happen for *all* GUI applications?  `xterm` for instance?  Thanks!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds: integrated the reply to your question in the text: yes, same problem with firefox, xterm, xclock, gedit.

Comment: Thanks!  Okay, so I don't see any open issues on this on the WSL Github.  Not quite sure what's going on, so I'm noodling debugging here -- You say that the apps "start", so I'm curious what "state" they are in.  After starting `xterm`, does the focus seem to shift to it?  If you start typing, do you think the input is going to Xterm?  I'm wondering if typing `exit` <kbd>Return</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> will get rid of it?  That would tell us that it is fully up and running, and receiving input, at least.  Then might be able to use `xdotool` with it to see what else we can see.

Comment: Seem that it is fixed in 1.1.3.0...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be fixed after a WSL upgrade. I don't know what changed, but here is the working configuration:

```
Version WSL : 1.1.3.0
Version du noyau : 5.15.90.1
Version WSLg : 1.0.49
Version MSRDC : 1.2.3770
Version direct3D : 1.608.2-61064218
Version de DXCore : 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
version Windows : 10.0.19044.2486
```

The update happened around march 1 2023, but I don't know when it was initially released.

Comment: February 14th, apparently.  A heads-up that you can see the release notes and all releases [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/releases) on the WSL Github repo.  Note that it could have been fixed in 1.1.0 or 1.1.2 also, since they were "pre-release" candidates that didn't role out with automatic updates.